# How do I control the number of elements in a nested list?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a function to loop through weblinks and extract the relevant tables.

```
List.Of.Tabs <- map(pages2, ~ {

  name <- .x[1]
  link <- .x[2]
  Sys.sleep(2)
  webpage <- read_html(link)
  tbls <- html_nodes(webpage, "table")
  tbls_ls <- html_table(tbls, fill = TRUE)
  pos1 <- possibly(function(tbls) bind_rows(tbls) %>% 
                     filter_all(any_vars(. %in% c("Singapore", "SGP"))) %>%
                     mutate(name = name) 
                   , otherwise = NA)

  pos1(tbls_ls)
})
```

However, on some occassion, I got this message:

```
Error in matrix(NA_character_, nrow = n, ncol = maxp) : 
  invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In max(p) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In matrix(NA_character_, nrow = n, ncol = maxp) :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

I figured it was due to some lists in `pages2` having more than 2 elements.

```
print(pages2)

[[48]]
[1] "DICK'S SPORTING GOODS, INC. "                                                                  
[2] "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1089063/000108906319000017/dks-exhibit_21x20190202.htm"

[[49]]
[1] "DIEBOLD NIXDORF, Inc "                                                                 
[2] "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/28823/000002882319000069/dbd12312018ex-211.htm"

[[50]]
[1] "DIGITAL REALTY TRUST, INC. "                                                               
[2] "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1297996/000129799619000032/dlr10kex211_2018ss1.htm"
[3] "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1297996/000129799619000032/dlr10kex212_2018ss1.htm"
```

How can I amend my code such that the error doesn't appear?

Comment: By saying "pages2' having more than 2 character", do you mean there are two links (e.g., the last list)?

Comment: I tried your code with the links you provided. Your code is working with these links. I do not understand your issues based on the present available information. Can you explain more?

Comment: @jazzurro yes that's right. I wonder if that is the problem? How do I control it such that each list only has 2 elements?

Comment: @jazzurro could you kindly explain what does that error message that I got mean? Or what potential problems I have with my dataset that will prompt such error message?

Comment: I wrote my code last night. Let me leave it for you. I basically arranged a data frame based on the list. I wonder if my approach works with your real case. I won't be able to help you next several hours. I hope you do not mind that.

Comment: Can you test my code with your real data and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot replicate the error messages with the provided links. But I can revise your code. You have lists with a company name and URL(s). Since you are specifying `link <- .x[2]`, you use the first URL in each list. If you arrange a data frame, you can overcome this issue. I created a data frame based on the list object you provided. One column has company names, and the other contains URLs. `map2_df()` uses a company name and an URL in each row and scrape the tables. In this way, you can make sure that you access to all URLs you have.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse) 

page2 <- list(c("DICK'S SPORTING GOODS, INC.", "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1089063/000108906319000017/dks-exhibit_21x20190202.htm"),
              c("DIEBOLD NIXDORF, Inc", "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/28823/000002882319000069/dbd12312018ex-211.htm"),
              c("DIGITAL REALTY TRUST, INC.", "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1297996/000129799619000032/dlr10kex211_2018ss1.htm", "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1297996/000129799619000032/dlr10kex212_2018ss1.htm"))

# Create a data frame based on page2
map_dfr(.x = page2,
        .f = function(x){tibble(company = x[1],
                                url = grep(x = x, pattern = "https", value = TRUE))}) -> mytemp

# For each pair of company and url (for each row with company and url),
# scrape tables, bind lists, add a new column with a company name, and
# get rows that have Singapore or SGP

map2_df(.x = mytemp$url,
        .y = mytemp$company,
        .f = function(x, y){read_html(x) %>% 
                            html_nodes("table") %>% 
                            html_table(fill = TRUE) %>% 
                            bind_rows() %>% 
                            mutate(name = y)}) %>% 
filter_all(any_vars(. %in% c("Singapore", "SGP")))

   name                       X1                                      X2        X3        
   <chr>                      <chr>                                   <chr>     <chr>     
 1 DIEBOLD NIXDORF, Inc       Aisino Wincor Engineering Pte. Ltd.     Singapore 43.56%(71)
 2 DIEBOLD NIXDORF, Inc       Diebold Nixdorf Manufacturing Pte. Ltd. Singapore 94.72%(66)
 3 DIEBOLD NIXDORF, Inc       Diebold Nixdorf Singapore Pte. Ltd.     Singapore 94.72%(51)
 4 DIGITAL REALTY TRUST, INC. Digital Investment Management Pte. Ltd. NA        Singapore 
 5 DIGITAL REALTY TRUST, INC. Digital Japan 1 Pte. Ltd.               NA        Singapore 
 6 DIGITAL REALTY TRUST, INC. Digital Japan 2 Pte. Ltd.               NA        Singapore 
 7 DIGITAL REALTY TRUST, INC. Digital Japan Holding Pte. Ltd.         NA        Singapore 
 8 DIGITAL REALTY TRUST, INC. Digital Singapore 1 Pte. Ltd.           NA        Singapore 
 9 DIGITAL REALTY TRUST, INC. Digital Singapore 2 Pte. Ltd.           NA        Singapore 
10 DIGITAL REALTY TRUST, INC. Digital Singapore Jurong East Pte. Ltd. NA        Singapore 
11 DIGITAL REALTY TRUST, INC. Digital Investment Management Pte. Ltd. NA        Singapore 
12 DIGITAL REALTY TRUST, INC. Digital Japan 1 Pte. Ltd.               NA        Singapore 
13 DIGITAL REALTY TRUST, INC. Digital Japan 2 Pte. Ltd.               NA        Singapore 
14 DIGITAL REALTY TRUST, INC. Digital Japan Holding Pte. Ltd.         NA        Singapore 
15 DIGITAL REALTY TRUST, INC. Digital Singapore 1 Pte. Ltd.           NA        Singapore 
16 DIGITAL REALTY TRUST, INC. Digital Singapore 2 Pte. Ltd.           NA        Singapore 
17 DIGITAL REALTY TRUST, INC. Digital Singapore Jurong East Pte. Ltd. NA        Singapore
```

**BONUS**

Given your comment, I think the following would work. Please note that I do not have your real data. So this idea may/may not work. This is the best I can do.

```
map2_dfr(.x = mytemp$url,
         .y = mytemp$company,
         .f = function(x, y){read_html(x) %>% 
                 html_nodes("table") %>% 
                 html_table(fill = TRUE) %>% 
                 map(.f = ~mutate_all(., .funs = list(~as.character(.)))) %>% 
                 bind_rows() %>% 
                 mutate(name = y)}) %>% 
filter_all(any_vars(. %in% c("Singapore", "SGP")))
```

Comment: I tried it on my data but I got the error `Error during wrapup: Column X3 can't be converted from character to numeric`

Comment: @Jane I am guessing that column has character and numeric both, and R is trying to have numeric values. But that is somehow prohibited. One thing I would try is to convert X3 to character in `map2_df()`. I think you would want to do this before `bind_rows() `. All is speculation given I do not have your real data.

Comment: thanks. but how do I do it if this error can occur to any of the columns? In this instance it may be X3 being the problematic column, but in other instances it could be X5 or X6 etc.?

Comment: @Jane If you do not know which columns contain character or numeric, I think you can convert all columns to character first. This process should be done before you use `bind_rows()` as well. Later, you can clean up some unnecessary characters and create numeric columns.

Comment: I tried using mutate_all `html_table(fill = TRUE) %>% mutate_all(as.character) %>%  bind_rows() %>%' but got this error `Error during wrapup: no applicable method for tbl_vars applied to an object of class "list"`

Comment: @Jane I revised my code. I hope this works for you. I am off to bed right after this. So I won't be able to help you till tomorrow.